# В поисках хэш функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, хеширование

Добрый день! До сих пор не пользовался хэш таблицами, но когда стало нужно, у меня возник вопрос:

Почему  нельзя пользоваться такой хэш функцией?

```
template <class T>
int my_hash(const T& p)
{
    T* pi = new T(p);
    uint32_t x = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(pi);
    return x % 105;
}
```

Comment: Кроме того что ваша функция не удовлетворяет требованиям, предъявляемым к классическому определению хэш-функции, в ней ещё и память утекает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пользоваться можно, вот только результат будет немного не предсказуем. Хеш функция должна для одинаковых объектов выдавать одинаковые значения. Для разных - желательно. Ваша функция не зависит от внутреннего устройства объекта. Более того, даже два одинаковых объекта скорее всего будут иметь разный разный хеш (если только это не один и тот же указатель).

Comment: очень даже  корото   и  ясно !...

Comment: а по поводу хэш значения - вероятность большая, что часто будет одно и то же значение  у такой хэш?

Comment: судя по всему - 1/105, то есть, в районе 1 процента

Comment: извените за настойчивость - последное уточнение:  тогда  насколько хороша будет такая функция  в  определении класса случайных чисел?  Рекомендуете ли вы пользоваться таки подходом?

Comment: Я не знаю такого класса, где эта функция была бы хороша. Но, возможно, в классе случайных чисел и была бы (но я сильно сомневаюсь), но я кода этого класса не видел.

Answer (score 3):

Общее требование - хеш должен зависеть только от хешируемого значения, и **обязан совпадать** для одинаковых значений. Иначе не будет работать сам принцип хеширования!

Ваш хэш, по большому счету, ничем не отличается от взятия произвольного случайного числа в качестве хэша. *Уж лучше вы бы для всех значений брали одно и то же число*, скажем, 0 - имели бы линейный список, который по крайней мере медленно, но корректно работал. В отличие от вашего варианта, который работать не будет вовсе...

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно, что значит ваше "нельзя".

- Во-первых, этой функцией "нельзя" пользоваться потому, что она на первый взгляд содержит грубую утечку памяти. Но это "нельзя" к хешированию никакого отношения не имеет. (Можно предположить, что конструктор типа `T` таки предотвращает утечку, но это уже домыслы.)
- Во-вторых, вопрос в том, что именно вы хотите хешировать. Значение указателя? Значение указуемого объекта? Эта функция пытается хешировать значение [утекающего] указателя. В хешировании указателей ничего плохого нет - это нередко бывает нужно. Но кому и зачем может понадобиться хешировать *утекающие* указатели? Однако если по какой-то специальной причине это именно то, что вам нужно, то такой функцией пользоваться "можно".
- В-третьих, эта функция хеширует значение указателя, но делает это некачественно. В качественной функции хеширования каждый бит хеша должен зависеть от каждого значащего бита хешируемого значения. Ваша функция же полностью игнорирует старшие биты хешируемого указателя. Эта функция хеширования некачественна, и с этой точки зрения ее использовать "нельзя".

То есть, если предположить, что проблема утечки памяти решена за кулисами, то у вас получилась странная и некачественная, но формально корректная функция хеширования указателя, которой "можно" пользоваться. А уж что именно вы хотели получить - известно только вам.

Comment: В трёх словах: 1. Опасная. 2. Нишевая (причём ниша, скорее всего, пустая). 3. Неэффективная.

Comment: @AnT, если вы имеете ввиду тот факт, что в функции не удаляется указатель, то смысль не в этом - это уже детали, а смысль вопроса в другом. Сейчас вы скажете нет в программировании неважных деталей, и я отвечу, что это не код, а набросок для  возможности задать интересующий мне вопрос. Как вы понели, я уже давно все выяснил и принял ответ....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan: Это прекрасно, но если абстрагироваться от всех "деталей", то принятый вами ответ - неправилен, как, впрочем, и исходный посыл вопроса. Ваша функция хеширования формально совершенно корректна и пользоваться ей можно.

Comment: @AnT, можно, но не нужно ( мне именно так и ответили...), и  в принципе я сам должен был знать это, просто догодался после ответа. Спасибо вам!